# Repeat specific elements of a tensor using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, repeat, tensor

I am using a 4-D tensor of shape=(N, 2, 127, 52)

I used:

```
tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(tensor, 2, axis=3)
```

This duplicate the last axis size from 52 to 104 by repeating each value:

shape=(N, 2, 127, 104)

Now I want to the same but only with the last 10 elements from the third axis having now:

shape=(N, 2, 127, 114)

I am also looking how to add an extra "*column*" by adding a zero vector in the middle of the last axis tensor resulting:

shape=(N, 2, 127, 115)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `tf.concat` would be a simple way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = 2
tensor = tf.random.normal((N, 2, 127, 52))
tensor = tf.repeat(tensor, 2, axis=3)

# (N, 2, 127, 114)
tensor = tf.concat([tensor, tensor[..., tf.shape(tensor)[-1]-10:]], axis=-1)

# (N, 2, 127, 115)
middle = tf.shape(tensor)[-1]//2
tensor = tf.concat([tensor[..., :middle], tf.zeros((N, 2, 127, 1)), tensor[..., middle:]], axis=-1)

print(tensor.shape)
```

```
(2, 2, 127, 115)
```